# Javascript How to enable asp Timer element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I set a asp:Timer control in aspx like this:

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>
```

and I have to enable it using javascript due to some reason,my javascript code is this(but not work):

```
function btnAuthorizeClient_Click() {
    var timer1 = document.getElementById("Timer1").value;
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    console.log('Success');
}
```

but it's useless,can someone help me ? Best Regards.